Excel 2019: reassign zoom shortcut keys?
Most of my apps zoom out and in with ctrl-minus and ctrl-equals.  So, I programmed such macros in Office 2003 and am happy with them and totally used to them.
I see Excel 2019 has zoom keys for ctrl-alt-minus and ctrl-alt-equals.  This is good, because I don't have to program them like I did in 2003.  But, I don't see a way to simply change the bindings for these.
I have tried to capture a macro with Developer->RecordMacro, zoom-out, and Developer->StopRecording.  But the macro just says
sub FSZoomIn()
'
' FSZoomIn Macro
'

'
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 85
End Sub

In short, I don't see what command ctrl-alt-equal ran, only what its logic determined was the action to take given the current zoom.  I was hoping to see something like ZoomInAnAppropriateAmountGivenCurrentZoom
Secondly, the new macro can only be assigned to ctrl-alphabet combinations, so ctrl-equal is not possible.
To fix this second problem, Google turned up advice to use this command in a THIRD macro that would assign the shortcuts to the keys I wanted:
Sub FSZoo
mAssign()
'
' FSZoomAssign Macro
'
Application.OnKey "^-", "FSZoomOut"
Application.OnKey "^=", "FSZoomIn"

End Sub

That actually works.  But after relaunching, I have to run this FSZoomAssign macro by hand in order to have these keys assigned.
The third problem is that these seem to be saved in the .xlsm file, instead of (as I did in Word 2003) in a document template or similar.  I'd like to be able to use the assigned shortcut keys with any document I open, not merely ones I'm able to add macros to.

You can run that using the open event from your personal.xlsm
